# Best way to deploy/publish Angular project with WEB Api backend

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, iis, deployment

I am working on my first Angular project. Angular frontend with a WEB Api backend which all works locally as expected, is there a best practice or best approach to deploying both the Frontend and Backend in one go for IIS? I'd prefer not to need to deploy them separately.

Comment: We usually deploy the build output to root of the IIS web site and create a virtual application in a subfolder (/api for the most part) where we deploy the Web API backend. Needs two separate deployments, though. I'd advise against packing the Angular SPA into a ASP.NET Core project due to the better flexibility of having to separate code bases that can be developed/updated independently.

Comment: Thank you, after thinking about it, it makes more sense to have them separate. I am however having issues calling the WEB API from the Angular app which are both now on separate deployments on IIS.

Comment: Whether it is a site or a sub-application under the site in IIS, it cannot be deployed at one time unless you use web deploy to write a general script to achieve one-click deployment.  `having issues calling the WEB API from the Angular app` Standalone sites use standalone domains, so is it a CORS error? Or other errors?

Comment: As @BruceZhang mentioned, CORS is the likely root of the connection problems if app and API are hosted under different origins. If you host the API in a virtual application below the app, you can avoid that. Otherwise, you need to configure your API to allow requests from the origin of the app (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: I was getting a CORS error, I added the below to my WebAPI Program.cs file and it worked once I published that. Thank you all for the responses. 



`app.UseCors(builder =>
  builder
  .AllowAnyOrigin()
  .AllowAnyHeader()
  .AllowAnyMethod()
  ); `